# Understanding formula components for Complex exponential sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-numbers, exponential-function

I am trying to understand how all components within the complex exponential sequence function fit together, I have been reading from the following slide [image]

it is the line below 'then we can express' that confuses me. so far I have deduced the following (which may be incorrect):
[image]

My confusion lies in two areas:

1) The part of the function used for magnitude looks awfully similar to what I would expect to see for rotation in the complex plane, how has this been used for magnitude?

2) The part of the function used to denote the base, has been converted into another form of which I do not understand.

If anyone could shed any light on either of these point it would be very much appreciated. If it is able to be explained intuitively as opposed to algebraically this would be much better as I have found the visualisation of the components working together allow for a better overall understanding.

Answer (score 1):

The context of "sequence" suggest that $n$ should be an *integer* in 
$$
x[n]=A\alpha^n.\tag{0}
$$

Your slide says **if we write**
$$
\alpha=e^{\sigma_0+j\omega_0},\quad A=|A|e^{j\phi},\tag{1}
$$
then
$$
x[n]=A\alpha^n=(|A|e^{j\phi})\cdot (e^{\sigma_0+j\omega_0})^n
=|A|e^{j\phi}e^{(\sigma_0+j\omega_0)n}.\tag{2}
$$
This is nothing but substitution (1) into (0).

For your second question, check [Euler's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula).

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, I understand that Eulers formula shows that we can use e^jϕ in the place of  cos(ϕ) + jsin(ϕ), however I am still unsure of the meaning of e^σ0+jω, could this be seen as the equivalent of the sum of two sets of coordinates when thinking in terms of e^jϕ = cos(ϕ) + jsin(ϕ)? Please could you elaborate a little further on the meaning of why there are two exponents being added in e^σ0+jω?

Comment: so the A part is a co-ordinate on the complex plane multiplied by the magnitude.. what is the α part? I take it it has something to do with frequency in radians per second due to the omega however it is the fact there are two variables within the brackets that is throwing me off.

Comment: Any complex number $z\neq 0$ can be written as $z=|z|e^{j\theta}$ for some real number $\theta$. Hence one can write $A=|A|e^{j\phi}$ for some $\phi$. Similarly, the complex number $\alpha$ can be written as $\alpha=|\alpha|e^{j\omega_0}$ for some real number $\omega_0$. Now, if one sets $\sigma_0=\ln |\alpha|$, assuming that $\alpha\neq 0$, then one can write $\alpha=e^{\sigma_0}e^{j\omega_0}=e^{\sigma_0+j\omega_0}$.

Comment: So what would be the purpose of multiplying the $eσ^0ejω^0$ together? what does it describe?

Comment: @FlewittConnor That requires more context than the slide shows to explain why and that's another question. All you slide does is nothing but replacing $|\alpha|$ with $e^{\sigma_0}$ where $\sigma_0=\ln |\alpha|$.

Comment: @FlewittConnor: If you could show a few more slides, one may be able to tell why that particular construction.

Answer (score -1):

(1) They haven't used $e^{j\phi}$ to represent magnitude. They also didn't make any such claim elsewhere. You're the one somehow mistaking this for magnitude. This is a complex number, not a magnitude.

(2) I don't really understand what you mean here, but if you meant the expression for $\alpha,$ then it's not much different from the expression for $A.$ Here, we've simply expressed $\alpha$ in exponential form (this may be uniquely done for any nonzero complex number). That is, we write it in the form $e^{a+ib}=e^ae^{ib}=R(\cos b+i\sin b),$ where $R=|\alpha|$ is a positive real number. So this is still of the form $|\alpha|e^{i\psi}$ for suitable $\psi.$

Comment: 1) I have mistaken this for magnitude, this is because so far my learnings have shown the $A$ will be the multiplier at the start which controls the amplitude of the signal, and with it having the $|A|$ I would expect this part to the the magnitude and the rest to denote the angle subtended from the base (the equivalent of R in $R(cosb+isinb)$.) can you please break down what it is if not that? 


What do the A and σ parts represent individually? If neither are magnitude?


2) yes, α being the base and n being the exponent, so is σ the cos b equivalent and J\omega_o equivalent of isin?

Comment: I wonder what the Good Downvoter finds objectionable about my explanations.